# Can't figure out how to close an open reference

Tags: python, pdf, delete-file

Basically I am extracting a page from a PDF, pasting a figured text into the extracted page, and saving the extracted page into the same folder. I've got everything to work as expected, but I end up with the pre-edited file that I cannot figure out how to close. The file I need to delete will always be 'delete.pdf'...but when I try deleting it at the end of the code, it says it is currently being used. I can't figure out how to close the last reference to the 'DELETE.pdf' file that is being edited. Any help will be appreciated, I am very new to Python.

I believe it is due to this opening (existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(open("DELETE.pdf", "rb")))

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import os 
import ntpath
import pdfplumber
import io
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.colors import HexColor

print('Paste the location of the file')
location = input()

plan = ntpath.basename(location)
os.chdir(location)
pdf = pdfplumber.open(plan +'.pdf')

page = pdf.pages[4]
text = page.extract_text()

ending = text.split("ft. or",1)[1]  
minimum = str(ending.split()[:1])

min2 = minimum[2:]
min3 = min2[:2]
Wording = (str(min3) + ' inches') 
pdf.close()

pdf_file_path = 'Plan.pdf'
file_base_name = pdf_file_path.replace('.pdf', '')
 
pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_file_path)
 
pages = [1] 
pdfWriter = PdfFileWriter()
 
for page_num in pages:
    pdfWriter.addPage(pdf.getPage(page_num))
 
with open('DELETE.pdf'.format(file_base_name), 'wb') as f:
    pdfWriter.write(f)
    f.close()

packet = io.BytesIO()

can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
can.setFillColor(HexColor(0xFF0000)) #sets color to red
can.setFont("Helvetica", 8) #sets font
can.drawString(75, 120, Wording) #inserts the min height
can.save()

#move to the beginning of the StringIO buffer
packet.seek(0)
new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)

# read your existing PDF
**existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(open("DELETE.pdf", "rb"))**
output = PdfFileWriter()

# add the "watermark" (which is the new pdf) on the existing page
page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))
output.addPage(page)

# finally, write "output" to a real file
with open('{0} New File.pdf'.format(file_base_name), "wb") as f:
    output.write(f)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Your tag is not enough. Use more tags please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly as you said, you aren't closing the opened file.
You could not make the changes here but instead just get a reference to the file before you use the `PdfFileReader` on it.
First option:

```
# read your existing PDF
read_pdf_file_handle = open("DELETE.pdf", "rb")
existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(read_pdf_file_handle)
output = PdfFileWriter()

# add the "watermark" (which is the new pdf) on the existing page
page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))
output.addPage(page)

# close the reference to it
read_pdf_file_handle.close()

# finally, write "output" to a real file
with open('{0} New File.pdf'.format(file_base_name), "wb") as f:
    output.write(f)
    # f.close() - unnecessary, file is closed on exiting the with statement
```

Second option:

```
# read your existing PDF
with open("DELETE.pdf", "rb") as read_pdf:
    existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(read_pdf)
    page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)

output = PdfFileWriter()

# add the "watermark" (which is the new pdf) on the existing page
page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))
output.addPage(page)

# finally, write "output" to a real file
with open('{0} New File.pdf'.format(file_base_name), "wb") as f:
    output.write(f)
    # f.close() - unnecessary, file is closed on exiting the with statement
```

Comment: First option worked. I had to move the .close command to the very end or it would result in a corrupted PDF for some reason. Thanks Mac!

Answer (score 0):

If you run the whole chunk of code that needs the pdf open inside a `with`, you don't need to close it.
This is the example from the [PdfPlumber GitHub docs](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber)

```
with pdfplumber.open("path/to/file.pdf") as pdf:
    first_page = pdf.pages[0]
    print(first_page.chars[0])
```